Calculate the area sweep by curves
$f:[0,a]\times [0,b]\rightarrow S$ is homeomorphism, where $S$ is a smooth surface. For any fixed $x_0\in[0,a]$, $f(x_0,y)$ is a curve, assume its normal vector is $N(x_0,y)$. I want to calculate  the area of $f([0,a]\times [0,b])$, denote the area as $A_f$. I guess it is
$$
A_f=\int_0^b\int_0^a |f_x(x,y)\cdot N(x,y)||f_y(x,y)| dx dy
\tag{1}
$$
I want to know whether it is right? And how to prove if it is right.
In fact, there is a slight geometric view in  (1), but my English is too poor to make it clear.
After X-Rui's advise, I revised my guess and calculate two example:
(I) Rectangle.  For constant $k,h\ne 0$, consider
$$
f:[0,1]\times[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R^2  ~~~~~~~~  
f(x,y)= (kx,hy)
$$
there is
$$
N(x,y)=(1,0),~~~f_x(x,y)=(k,0),~~~f_y(x,y)=(0,h)
$$
therefore
$$
|f_x(x,y)\cdot N(x,y)|=|k|~~~~~~|f_y(x,y)|=|h|
$$
From (1), there is
$$
A_f=|kh|
$$
(II) Half of unit circle. Consider
$$
f:[0,1]\times[0,\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb R^2~~~~~~
f(x,y)= (x\cos y, x\sin y)
$$
therefore
$$
N(x,y)=(\cos y, \sin y),~~~~
f_x(x,y)=(\cos y, \sin y),~~~~
f_y(x,y)=(-x\sin y, x\cos y)
$$
then
$$
|f_x(x,y)\cdot N(x,y)|=1~~~~~~|f_y(x,y)|=x
$$
From (1), there is
$$
A_f=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
The two example imply (1) is right. And I feel that the  integral change of variable theorem  may be useful to prove (1).  But it's too late today. I have to go to bed.

Schematic drawing



You'll want to integrate the Jacobian of $f$. See the integral change of variable theorem.

@aschepler Using Jacobian means that I need the coordinate of $S$. I don't do so, since I feel using the normal vector  may be enough. In fact, the tangent vector can be get by $f_y$.

If you are proposing a new formula, the burden of proof is on you. You should give some evidence showing its effectiveness, if you can’t prove it. Have you tried any examples? I suggest you start with $f(x,y)=(x,2y)$ for $(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

@X-Rui You are right. Only feel is not enough, try some examples is beneficial.  Thanks.

@aschepler  You were very impressive,  immediately saw that it was actually to integrate the Jacobian of  $f$.  I didn't see that at the time, and I was looking for a geometric explanation. Thanks very much.

Only when $S$ is part of $\mathbb R^2$, (1) is right. Assume
$$
f(x,y) = (u(x,y), v(x,y))
$$
then, there are
$$
f_x=(u_x, v_x) ~~~f_y=(u_y, v_y) ~~~N(x,y)=(-\frac{v_y}{|f_y|},  \frac{u_y}{|f_y|})
$$
Therefore, (1) become
$$
A_f=\int_0^b\int_0^a |\det
\begin{pmatrix}
u_x, u_y  \\
v_x,  v_y
\end{pmatrix}
| dx dy
=\int_{f([0,a]\times [0,b])} dudv
$$
But, generally, the area of $S$ should be
$$
\int_{f([0,a]\times [0,b])}  \sqrt{\det(g)} dudv
$$
where $g$ is first fundamental form of $S$.  Therefore, the right version should be
$$
A_f=\int_0^b\int_0^a |f_x(x,y)\cdot N(x,y)||f_y(x,y)| \sqrt{\det(g(f(x,y)))}dx dy
$$
